# Relational Database Normalization Issues

Tags: sql, database-design

My website is a job seek site. There are three types of users: `User`, `Employee` or `Admin`.

- `User` can search and apply for a job,
- `Employee` can post a job, browser resumes,
- `Admin` is to manage the site.

Here are all the tables that I defined.

```
-- Users table, users = jobseekers, containing jobseekers info  
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;
CREATE TABLE users (
  user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  pass CHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  user_phone VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  user_address VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  active CHAR(32) NULL,
  last_login_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                                     ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  last_login_ip VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  registration_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
  registration_ip VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
  UNIQUE KEY (email),
  INDEX login (email, pass)
) ENGINE = INNODB;


-- Employers table, containing employers info
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employers;
CREATE TABLE employers (
  employer_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  company_name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  pass CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  employer_phone VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
  employer_mobile VARCHAR(11),
  employer_address VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
  active CHAR(32) NULL,
  last_login_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                                     ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  last_login_ip VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  registration_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
  registration_ip VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (employer_id),
  UNIQUE KEY (email),
  INDEX login (email, pass)
) ENGINE = INNODB;


-- Administrators table, containing site administrators info
-- Note: move created_time after last_login_time, otherwise SQL error #1293
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS administrators;
CREATE TABLE administrators (
   admin_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   first_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
   last_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
   email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
   pass CHAR(40) NOT NULL,
   last_login_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                                     ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   last_login_ip VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
   created_time DATETIME NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (admin_id)
) ENGINE = INNODB;


-- CVs table, containing CV info
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cvs;
CREATE TABLE cvs (
   cv_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
   cv_name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
   user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   description VARCHAR(80),  
   PRIMARY KEY (cv_id)
) ENGINE = INNODB;


-- Jobs table, containing job information
-- Note: must use MYISAM to support Fulltext search
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS jobs;
CREATE TABLE jobs (
   job_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
   job_title VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   employer_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   company_name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
   description TEXT NOT NULL,
   town VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   county VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   contact_name VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
   contact_phone VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
   contact_email VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
   salary SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   confirm TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL default 0,
   posted_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
   deadline INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   job_status SET('open', 'closed') NOT NULL,  
   employer_paid SET('yes', 'no') NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (job_id),
   FULLTEXT (job_title, description)
) ENGINE = MYISAM;


-- Jobs users applied
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS jobs_applied;
CREATE TABLE jobs_applied (
   jobs_applied_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
   user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   cv_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   cv_name VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
   job_id INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   job_title VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   company_id INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   company_name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
   applied_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (jobs_applied_id)
) ENGINE = INNODB;


-- Reports table, containing info to produce site reports
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS reports;
CREATE TABLE reports (
   report_id INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
   user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   employer_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   job_id INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
   job_title VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
   job_posttime TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
   content VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
   report_time INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (report_id)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

Some people say the tables I designed are exactly what I must not do in a relational database because they are full of duplicates. I don't get it. Anyone take a look at my design please and point out the design errors?

Comment: you mean besides the three tables I defined for all users, there should be a new table like users_employers_admins? About User/Authorization management, are there any sample source code I can find? Does Wordpress or other PHP CMS have it?

Comment: I've added an answer explaining the general breakdown.

Answer (score 1):

The *biggest* issue that jumps out at me (although there are a few) is that half of the Employer and Administrator fields are really just part of User/Authorization management. Keep the concept of 'Seekers' and 'Employers' and 'Administrators' separate (separate tables are fine and will actually help with FK relations), but there should be a unified 'Users/Accounts' relation that they relate to.

For instance, imagine the three "role discriminating" tables. A User can be associated with zero or all three through DRI (SQL does not inherently support distributed FKs) so business rules should be in place to ensure that right associations - but why couldn't an Employer also be a Seeker?

These tables can contain additional information as *relate to the specific role* (Seeker, Employer, Admin). The benefit of keeping separate tables (instead of just a discriminating role column) is that;

1. Additional columns can be added to the refined type as required;
2. FKs can be established along role_id, instead of needing a two-part (user_id,role).

```
Seekers (people looking for jobs)
---
seeker_id (PK)
user_id (FK Users, not null)

Employers
---
employer_id (PK)
user_id (FK Users, not null)

Administrators
---
admin_id (PK)
user_id (FK Users, not null)

Users/Accounts
---
- All the data that relates to login/authorization information such as username
- and password salt/hash, account contact e-mail, etc.
- You probably want to separate the authentication such as login/auth information
- and additional details, such as "last login from" or "registered from", etc.
```

Most "CMS" systems will already have authentication and authorization schemes in-place.

---

Other things that should be normalized (but strike me far less than the duplicate discussed above) are "Contact Information" and "Companies/Locations". It might also be worthwhile separating a "Job" from a "JobListing". Also, there appear to be some fields that are simply duplicated without reason:

```
company_id INT(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
company_name VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
```

Since the relation *already* has the company_id for a FK/Join, the company_name column is simply duplicate data and should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to normalize your database schema / design to avoid storing duplicate data.

See this article on Normalization with Examples: [Description of the database normalization basics](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283878)

In your particular case, you should separate out the `Company`, `Contact`, `JobLocation`, `JobType`, `JobIndustry` etc into their own tables and use relationships to link them.